# How to use Grid.mvc with dynamic DataTable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Here is my try

```
@model System.Data.DataTable
@using GridMvc.Html

@Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
          {
                columns.Add(foo => foo.Title).Titled("Custom column title").SetWidth(110);
          })
```

I get error:

```
Unable to get the arguments of the method "GridMvc.Html.GridExtensions.Grid <T> (System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable <T>)" Use of Data
```

same with `.AutoGenerateColumns()`

I've got dynamic data tables (structures) but they are descripted inside specific `DataTable` . How can I use MVC Grid in this case?

Comment: Do you actually have a model class 'DataTable', or are you referring to actual c# DataTable?

Comment: @AmmarCSE std one, `System.Data.DataTable`

Comment: I believe that is where you problem is. The exception is complaining that it cannot determine the generic model type which it expects: System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable <T>

Comment: Take a look at https://gridmvc.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#GridMvc/GridMvc.Site/Models/Grids/OrdersGrid.cs which shows a working model example.